# Text label rotated 45 degrees

Tags: c#, text, coordinates

I have tried to make a rather simple example turning text labels in C#, by inserting the code below... All I have done beside this is to create a Form with a label called label1. The idea was to make the drawString start at label1's 0,0 and then rise towards right. 
Status is, that the text is written as intended BUT with failing X,Y coordinates. Good suggestions are welcome :-)

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Create string to draw.
    String drawString = "Text to start at label start";

    // Create font and brush.
    Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 8);
    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    // Create point for upper-left corner of drawing.
    PointF drawPoint = label1.Location;

    // Rotate -45 degrees 
    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-45);

    StringFormat formatter = new StringFormat();
    formatter.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
    formatter.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

    // Draw string to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint, formatter);
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
}
```

Regards
NewBee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-45);
```

The mistake you have made is thinking that this would rotate about the label when in fact it rotates about the canvas's (0, 0) point. You can get around this by shifting the canvas's (0, 0) to the label, performing the rotation, then shifting it back. Like this

```
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(drawPoint.X, drawPoint.Y);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(-45);
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-drawPoint.X, -drawPoint.Y);
```

It's worth noting the concept behind these transforms comes from Linear Algebra. Under the hood all of these methods work together to build one piece of data called the transformation matrix that then multiplies with each pixel coordinate in the label, resulting in the actual pixel coordinates to draw. Perhaps someone more well versed in the math can explain more in depth, but I'll stop there.